# Having Trouble with Apple's MusicKit SDK

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9-beta, apple-music

I am trying to create an application using the new MusicKit in the Xcode 9.0 beta. I have downloaded the sample application provided by Apple and replaced all the values in the code such as storefront, and the developer token. 
I have created my developer token and I know that it works because I have tested it with Apple Music API and I am getting positive results. However, when I run the sample application it seems like I'm getting an error in the requestUserToken() function. 
The exact error is `An error occurred when requesting user token: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 1.)`.

Please let me know if anyone has successfully acquired a user token in the Apple MusicKit SDK.

Comment: I'm no help to you, but could you point me in the right direction for how you created your developer token? I've been looking at Auth0 and have been confused about what to do.

Comment: You have to create a token with the JSON Web Token (JWI) encryption. The specific instructions are on the Apple Music API Documentation page ( here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1)

Comment: You can go to https://jwt.io/ to see where you can get the program to create the Dev Token

Comment: Thanks, yep I'd looked at Apple's docs, but it took me awhile to realize that jwt.io had links to all those repos. Trying out a ruby implementation today. Btw, if it's not too much trouble, what solution do you have for avoiding hardcoding the token in the app?

Comment: I followed Apple's suggestion and in the Xcode app I created a get request to a server and on that server I have the dev token.

Comment: Sorry to keep at this, but if you don't mind, what particular library did you use to create a JWT encrypted with ES256? I used ruby's jwt library but I think there was something missing (the call returned 403). It seems I may not be following apple's instructions to "sign it with the MusicKit private key." Apple's docs do not make it clear how to do that, and I have not found a library that makes this step clear either.

Comment: I can help. However, you'll be using the python 3 and I would need you to post the question on Stackoverflow because it might be too long for this comment section and others may find it helpful.

Comment: Ah, just found https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator and it did the trick! Thanks for your help.

Comment: The GitHub link to  github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator that Steve Cotner mentioned above was magic. The Apple docs are definitely not clear on how to generate the developer token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKErrorDomain code=1 is "clientInvalid" error.

Calling requestUserToken triggers iOS to ask for my Apple ID password for me. I get this error when I (the user) refuse to provide my password. I've just tried and verified this behaviour with the Apple's sample project as well. I would try to make sure "iTunes & AppStore" section on Settings app have a valid Apple ID provisioned. I would also try starting from sctratch by removing the app from the test device.

So, to answer your question; yes I can successfully can get userToken with the sample project (running on iOS 11 beta 2 physical device). The "Recents" tab is showing my player history.

Comment: Hm okay. I think my problem is that my iPhone Simulator on Xcode does not let me connect to "iTunes and App Store". I get the error `Could not sign in: There was a problem connecting to the server`.

Comment: I will have to run it on the test device until Apple allows the capability on the Xcode Simulator.

Comment: @JohnA did you manage to get this working? I am getting an SKDomainError 1. I have iTunes & AppStore set up with my Apple ID. I can't seem to successfully get a userToken though! `An error occurred when requesting user token: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 1.)`

Comment: @scgough are you running the app on a apple device or the xcode iPhone simulator?

Comment: @JohnA it's an iPhone 5s running ios11

Comment: I faced "Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=7" for generating user token, I am getting token in iPhone 6 with valid apple id.